# First call to skip() in minitest throws error (undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

Getting an undefined error on the first call to 'skip' in a rails 3.2/minitest project.

```
require "test_helper"

describe "Test Integration Test" do
  describe "area1" do
    it "must do X" do
      assert true
    end
    it "must do Y" do
      assert true
    end
  end
end
```

This works fine, but if I modify to skip Y...

```
    it "must do Y" do
      skip "need to rewrite"
      assert true
    end
```

... it errors:

```
$ rake test:integration
Run options: --seed 49388

.E

Finished tests in 2.109235s, 6.6375 tests/s, 12.8008 assertions/s.
# Running tests:

  1) Error:
test_0003_must_do_y(Test Integration Test::area1):
NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
    /Users/drew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:35:in `block in run'
    /Users/drew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__858522010476008514__setup__95624718422814153__callbacks'
    /Users/drew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    /Users/drew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_setup_callbacks'
    /Users/drew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    /Users/drew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:34:in `run'
```

If I add a third test, also skipped, it only reports an error on the first skip:

```
require "test_helper"

describe "Test Integration Test" do
  describe "area1" do
    it "must do X" do
      assert true
    end
    it "must do Y" do
      skip "rewrite me"
      assert true
    end
    it "must do Z" do
      skip "rewrite me"
      assert true
    end
  end
end


$ rake test:integration
Run options: --seed 43718

# Running tests:

ES.

Finished tests in 2.236945s, 6.2585 tests/s, 11.6230 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
test_0003_must_do_z(Test Integration Test::area1):
NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
    /Users/drew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:35:in `block in run'
    /Users/drew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__2453774402805069296__setup__401473829290905838__callbacks'
    /Users/drew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    /Users/drew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_setup_callbacks'
    /Users/drew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    /Users/drew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:34:in `run'
```

Can anyone offer a suggestion as to why the first skip encountered is erring? Or, perhaps, which issue tracker I should file this issue in?

Answer (score 0):

I debugged this and found that the error came from the minitest-rg gem I'm using. In case any others run into this issue, I [patched it in a fork](https://github.com/tacomanator/minitest-rg) and send a [pull request to the maintainer](https://github.com/radiospiel/minitest-rg/pull/1).